# Build a dictionary of selected features

Tags: python, dictionary, missing-features

I have 20K objects and a set of features provided in a list. I need to extract those features from each object and save them into a dictionary. Each object has almost 100 features.

For example:

```
# object1
Object1.Age = '20'
Object1.Gender = 'Female'
Object1.DOB = '03/05/1997'
Object1.Weight = '130lb'
Object1.Height = '5.5'

#object2
Object1.Age = '22'
Object1.Gender = 'Male'
Object1.DOB = '03/05/1995'
Object1.Weight = '145lb'
Object1.Height = '5.8'

#object3
Object1.Age = '22'
Object1.Gender = 'Male'
Object1.DOB = '03/05/1995'
Object1.Weight = '145lb'

#object4
...
```

And the list of features that I need to extract from each object (this list may change, so I need the code to be flexible about it):

```
features = ['Gender', 
        'DOB', 
        'Height']
```

Currently, I'm using this function to capture all the features that I need form each object:

```
def get_features(obj, features):
return {f: getattr(obj, f) for f in features}
```

This function works perfectly if all the objects have all the features that I want. But there are some objects that do not have all the features. For example object3 does not have a filed named "Height". How can I put NaN for the value of missing files in my dictionary so that I can prevent getting an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Python getattr documentation:](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#getattr)

> getattr(object, name[, **default**])
>   Return the value of the named attribute of object. name must be a string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, the result is the value of that attribute. For example, getattr(x, 'foobar') is equivalent to x.foobar. **If the named attribute does not exist, default is returned if provided, otherwise AttributeError is raised.**

You could just do this:

```
def get_features(obj, features):
    return {f: getattr(obj, f, float('Nan')) for f in features}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `obj.__dict__`:

```
def get_features(obj, features):
  return {f:obj.__dict__.get(f, 'NaN') for f in features}
```

Or, if you still wish to use `getattr`, you can implement `hasattr`:

```
def get_features(obj, features):
  return {f:'NaN' if not hasattr(obj, f) else getattr(obj, f) for f in features}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should return `NaN` as the default value if the key is not present:  `obj.__dict__.get(feature_name, float('NaN'))`

For Python 3.5+, `NaN` is available as a constant in the `math` package, so this would work `obj.__dict__.get(feature_name, math.nan)`